# Powershell - Delete all the oldest files when folder size reaches 5GB

Tags: powershell

Need you help in the below query. My requirement is to delete all the oldest files who together attain a total size of 5GB in the folder. But currently it is only deleting one file due to -first 1. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
$Dir = "L:\TraceFiles"
$MaxSize = 5120     #Specify in MB
$Filter = "*.trc"

$OldestFile = Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter $Filter | Sort LastWriteTime  | Select -First 1 
$FolderCurrentSize = (Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum / 1MB

IF ($FolderCurrentSize -GT $MaxSize)
        {
        Write-output "Deleting File $OldestFile, becuase the Current folder size $FolderCurrentSize MB, has exceeded the maximum size of $MaxSize MB"
        #Remove-Item $OldestFile.FullName
        }
ELSE
        {
        Write-output "No deletes needed! Current folder size is $FolderCurrentSize MB, which is less than maximum size of $MaxSize MB"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Martin and Avshalom for inputs. Got the solution finally as below using the foreach loop. Really thanks for your ideas.

```
$Dir = "L:\TraceFiles"
$MaxSize = 5120     #Specify in MB
$Filter = "*.trc"

$OldestFilesAll = Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter $Filter | Sort LastWriteTime 

IF ($FolderCurrentSize -GT $MaxSize)
{
        foreach($File in $OldestFilesAll)
        {

        $OldestFileSingle = Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter $Filter | Sort LastWriteTime  | Select -First 1
        $FolderCurrentSize = (Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum / 1MB

        IF ($FolderCurrentSize -GT $MaxSize)
                {
                Write-output "Deleting File $OldestFileSingle, becuase the Current folder size $FolderCurrentSize MB, has exceeded the maximum size of $MaxSize MB"
                Remove-Item $OldestFileSingle.FullName
                }
        }
}

ELSE
        {
        Write-output "No deletes needed! Current folder size is $FolderCurrentSize MB, which is less than maximum size of $MaxSize MB"

        }
```

Comment: I think your answer got downvoted for forgetting the first line with $FolderCurrentSize just after defining $OldestFilesAll.

Answer (score 0):

Add a LastWriteTime filter to The `$OldestFile` and remove the `Select -Last 1`

```
$OldestFile = Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter $Filter | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -lt "01/01/2014"}

$Sum = 0; $OldestFile | % {$sum += $_.length}
$TotalSize = $Sum /1mb
```

Use Foreach to remove each file found: in case them all are greater then 5gb

```
IF ($TotalSize -GT $MaxSize)
{
    foreach ($file in $oldestfile)
        {
        remove-item $file -WhatIf
        }
}

## Remove the -WhatIf if it's do the work...
```

Comment: This will remove everything older than 01/01/2014, not checking the dir size requirement.

Comment: You are still removing all files older than given date. You are not removing oldest files, which exceeds the dirs max size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like  `wile Directory size > 5gb, get oldest file, delete it`.

in PS:

```
while ( ((Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum / 1MB) -gt $MaxSize)
{
    $OldestFile = Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter $Filter | Sort LastWriteTime  | Select -First 1 
    #Remove-Item $OldestFile.FullName
}
```

Comment: The question is about older files, when foldersize is exceeded. Not just files older than x.
Thats excatly, what the while loop does.
It checks, if the requirement is met and removes (only) the oldest file. After that it rechecks the requirement and so forth.
Did i missed something?
I'm sure, it could be done more pretty, but it works :)

Comment: As I understand the question, `My requirement is to delete all the oldest files who together attain a total size of 5GB` if all the old files in the folder are together greater then 5gb delete them all, your solution will delete each file until the folder size will be lower then 5gb, also will degrade performance as it check the size of the folder over and over

Comment: Now i got you. You are totally right about the performance thing. 
The Write-Output Statements are pointing to a 5GB folder size requirement, the question is pointing in a different direction.